# How can you adjust Android SnackBar to a specific position on screen

Tags: android, android-view, android-snackbar, snackbar

Follwing the new android snackbar, i'm trying to set it to be positioned on a specific y coordinate. Its seems to be not even a possible.

I've tried with getting the parent of the snackbar's view, but, there's nothing to be done to the parent for it to set the position of it.

```
mSnackBar.getView().getParent();
```

When digging into the actual class, there's an instance of mView, and mParent which is private, and can't be reached anyhow.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It is possible to set the location that the Snackbar is displayed by positioning a `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` within your existing Activity layout.

For example, say your existing layout is a `RelativeLayout` you could add a `CoordinatorLayout` as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then, make sure you pass the `CoordinatorLayout` as the first argument of the `Snackbar.make()` command.

```
final View viewPos = findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout);    
Snackbar.make(viewPos, R.string.snackbar_text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction(R.string.snackbar_action_undo, showListener)
                            .show();
```

This will result in the Snackbar being shown at the **bottom** of the `CoordinatorLayout` provided to the make() function.

If you pass a `View` that is not a `CoordinatorLayout` the Snackbar will walk up the tree until it finds a `CoordinatorLayout` or the root of the layout.

Comment: @BrentM, is there any way to display according to the design guidelines - i.e. centered + floating with some padding at the bottom ? I got it left aligned without padding instead.  http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html

Comment: @Angel Adding a CoordinatorLayout with `android:paddingBottom="16dp"` and `android:layout_width="match_parent"` should allow you to control the positioning.

Comment: This seems to work perfect. My requirement is to show 2 snackbars in a fragment. So, I added 2 coordinator layouts and passed, them to the respective `Snackbar` objects. However, when the second one appears, the first one goes away. Is there a way to keep both of them visible?

Comment: If you are using Android X, you can use setAnchorView method. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/BaseTransientBottomBar.html#setanchorview

Answer (score 14):

Defining a layout explicitly for the Snackbar may not always be practical.

The issue seems to have been targeting the parent, rather than the Snackbar.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(layout, message, duration);
View snackbarLayout = snackbar.getView();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
// Layout must match parent layout type
lp.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0);
// Margins relative to the parent view.
// This would be 50 from the top left.
snackbarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: I made a repository based on your answer:
https://github.com/LucasFebatis/customsnackbar

Comment: @LucasBatista Probably best to provide attribution there if you intend to advertise here.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. How can I provide attribution?

Answer (score 7):

I have an interesting idea for you.

You can just use the code below to get where you want.

```
Snackbar.make(View,Message , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
.setAnchorView(pb)
.show();
```

Here `setAnchorView` is used to change the postion. You can create your layout in the xml file. Just call your layout inside the `setAnchorView` and it will show on the position of the xml layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setAnchorView (@IdRes int anchorViewId) method of a snackbar to set it above anchor view

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar#make(android.view.View,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)

Answer (score -1):

In addition to [brentm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4517878/brentm)'s answer, I had to use:

`androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`

and add the dependency for it:

`implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0"`