# Where is an Android Snackbar that will enter from right

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I try to find a [Android snackbar](https://github.com/search?l=Java&o=desc&p=6&q=snackbar&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) typ of widget that will enter not from top or bottom but from right or left. Further demands is custom message, icon, stacking, dismiss button, callback handlers. The thing is when snackbar is popping up from the bottom it can block keyboard or EditText. The eyecatcher is also more natural if snackbar message come from right and is centered vertically on device screen

btw, Windows 10 have this notifications popping out from the right behaving in general exactly like Android Toast

Another behavior on this snack is that when snackbar(if we now can still call it a snackbar) is that when it pops out from the right it can have a graphical progress bar under message text counting down from like 3 sec or 5 sec or whatever duration was chosen before snackbar pop back and disappear. This is simply in respect for the user who is attacked by the snack, to let him know when snack go away..

Any ide?

Answer (score 0):

You can read answers to similar question here: [How can you adjust Android SnackBar to a specific position on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492351/how-can-you-adjust-android-snackbar-to-a-specific-position-on-screen)
I hope you will find helpful advice on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your snackbar to come from right side, If your version is more than lollipop then use Slide function and set the view in slide function it will come from right only